# Comparing objects and enum class?

Tags: java

I have enum class, something like this:

```
public enum ProductCategory {
    FOOD("FOOD"), 
    BEVERAGE("BEVERAGE"), 
    DEFAULT("DEFAULT");

    private final String label;

    private ProductCategory(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

And I want to write method that will compare two objects based on the ProductCategory. So if two objects have the same category (for example: FOOD), the method will return true.

```
public boolean searchFilterFunction(Object firstObject, Object secondObject) {
    if(firstObject==null || secondObject==null)
        return false;

    //code?
    return true;
}
```

Enum class is in one package, and the method I want to write is in another. Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: Do the arguments need to be `Object` only?

Comment: @DarshanMehta yes

Answer (score 2):

> I want to write method that will compare two objects based on the `ProductCategory`

Java objects do not have an associated `ProductCategory`.

If your custom objects have one, you can write a method for checking it as if it were a primitive type:

```
public boolean searchFilterFunction(Product one, Product two) {
    return one != null
        && two != null
        && one.getProductCategory() == two.getProductCategory();
}
```

Comment: Please note that OP wants the arguments to be of `Object` type only.

Comment: @DarshanMehta That's what I talk about at the top of my answer, she needs a way to associate a category to her object. It wouldn't work on `java.lang.Object`, unless there's some mechanism to establish the object-to-category link.

Answer (score 1):

Enum constants are singletons and, in such a case, they can be conveniently tested for equality using the '==' operator (because, for singletons, value can never be separated from identity ... this is not true for ordinary object instances). For example:

```
if (thisEnum == ProductCategory.FOOD) System.out.println("It's a food");
```

If you have a need to test arbitrary objects of any type for equality with an enum, then you don't need to re-invent the wheel.  There is already a null safe method in the convenience class `Objects` that will do this:

```
if (Objects.equals(myEnum, ProductCategory.FOOD)) System.out.println("It's a food");
```